# cmake/cpack doesn't recognize inter-component dependencies

Tags: linux, cmake, package, deb, cpack

I am trying to convince cmake/cpack to build a shared library package (component `lib`) and a development package (component `dev`).

The `lib` component should only contain the shared library, and should have no dependencies.

The `dev` component should only contain the header file, and should depend on the `lib` component.

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(libmy)

add_library(my SHARED src/main/my.c)

target_include_directories(my PUBLIC include)

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "peter.spierenburg@nautel.com")

install(TARGETS my
  LIBRARY
  DESTINATION /usr/local/lib
  COMPONENT lib)

install(FILES include/my.h
  DESTINATION /usr/local/include
  COMPONENT dev)

set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_ENABLE_COMPONENT_DEPENDS ON)

include(CPack)

cpack_add_component(lib REQUIRED)
cpack_add_component(dev DEPENDS lib)
```

A build nets me two deb packages `libmy-0.1.1-Linux-dev.deb` and `libmy-0.1.1-Linux-lib.deb`. However, the `dev` package does not depend on the `lib` package.